# How do I update multiple nested array documents using mongodp with php?

Tags: php, mongodb

I was trying to update the data on a nested array. I was able to do so using a positional operator, but the problem I am having is I cannot get multiple documents to be updated. My document structure is like:

```
'items' => array (
    0 => array (    
        'name' => 'soap',
        'qty' => 5,
        'price' => 2.5,
    ),
    1 => 
        array (
        'name' => 'soap',
        'qty' => 5,
        'price' => 2.5,
    ),
);
```

I wanted to update all the name field where 'name'=>soap. I wrote the following code:

```
$newdata = array('$set'=> array('items.$.name'=> "paste"));

$collection->update(
    array('items.name' => "soap"),
    $newdata,
    array("multiple"=>true)
);
```

The above code worked for the first entry but its not updating the other data entries, even when the multiple option is set to true.

Can anyone give me a working solution as to how to update all the datas having item name as soap? Thankz in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option `multiple => true` has effect on multiple **documents**. What you want is to update multiple **sub-documents** with one update statement. And this you can't do. If this is a requirement of your application, then you need to change your schema to have each of the elements in your `items` array to be separate documents.

Comment: Hey Derick, Thanks for the reply. I get your point. Since m a noob  in mongo, I hope you wouldn't mind answering, Since the DB is schema less how do I make a relation between documents(tables) if I need to make separate documents for all? Do i need to do that on the coding side itself?

Comment: Maybe, I think you've only showed a part of your document structure by just showing the "items" field?

Comment: Yeah actually considering that this is a table for a shopping app there are fields like customer id and the rest. Should I use the manual reference technique and make the relation? Will that be more advisable?